# How often are satellites in GEO moved to follow customer demand?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, geostationary, commercial

The BBC News article [Inmarsat lays big satellite order with Airbus](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-48455168) says:

> The firm is buying three new spacecraft to augment its Global Xpress system, which provides connectivity to on-the-move and out-of-the-way users, such as those on ships, planes and oil rigs.
>
> European aerospace giant Airbus will build the satellites.
>
> Inmarsat says their novel technologies will make it easier and faster to react to market developments.
>
> **For example, rather than taking up a "fixed" position in the sky, as is the case with all the company's current platforms, these new spacecraft will be designed with the expectation that they might have to move around to match demand.**
>
> Their telecommunications payloads will also be fully reconfigurable through software updates - not something that is generally practised today.

Is it unusual for satellites in GEO to move around in longitude to adjust to the geographical distribution of customer demand? Are there any current examples of this kind of activity, apart from an occasional one-off major repurposing?

Comment: This reminds me (a little bit) of the "dedicated satellites" in [Enemy of the State](https://youtu.be/TTzl0PzPiK0?t=48) (see also [Is the Hollywood “Enemy of the State” satellite at all based on a real satellite?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28207/12102))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have have been working for a while (almost 4 years..) as a Satellite Control & Operations Engineer. According to my experience, a satellite must be located and stayed inside a *longitude* box. An example image can be seen below:

[image: Longitude Box of Satellite]

We had a similar *longitude* degree restrictions/limitations to keep satellite in that box. So, maneuvers are performing due to that issue in every 2 weeks..

- First week: E/W, regarding the season.
- Second week: N/S, regarding the season.

---

Anyway, changing the satellite's position/location, much bigger than the station-keeping maneuvers, is not a usual thing. I have seen and heard some examples of it, let me share it..

Assume that one company has two longitude rights (one of them is operating and other one is empty) and they have decided to launch another satellite. So, they can decide to re-locate the operating satellite to the empty location then they can put the new satellite into the old longitude location. This can happen due to fuel budget considerations etc. (company's decision), but this can be happen.

A different example can be seen [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41010/is-the-risk-of-explosion-induced-damage-to-operational-spacecraft-in-geo-actuall) also.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I will be more careful next time.

Comment: See for example [How to Drift a Satellite: What Happens when NOAA GOES-16 is Moved into Operational Position](https://www.nesdis.noaa.gov/content/how-drift-satellite-what-happens-when-noaa-goes-16-moved-operational-position) and [Satellite Repositioning Maneuver Detection in Geosynchronous Orbit Using Two-line Element (TLE) Data](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344631183_Satellite_Repositioning_Maneuver_Detection_in_Geosynchronous_Orbit_Using_Two-line_Element_TLE_Data)

Comment: Thanks for the useful links @uhoh

Comment: Per the second link, one of the following three moved in longitude by about 10 degrees in the first half of 2018 per Figure 1 and the text: "Inmarsat 3-F3 (Satellite ID #: 24674), Raduga 4 (Satellite ID #: 10987) and Intelsat 901 (Satellite ID #:
26824)."

Comment: And also COSMOS (Satellite ID #2542) from Russia, has been changed lot of positions in GEO belt due to some other issues in space.. We were tracking it while I was working at TURKSAT. [Source](https://www.thedrive.com/the-war-zone/32031/a-russian-inspector-spacecraft-now-appears-to-be-shadowing-an-american-spy-satellite).

Comment: @Onur great answer!